# Android Fragment com TextWatcher - não funciona

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, listener

Bom dia!
Com a ajuda do pessoal, fiz um esquema de calculo que ao digitar o valor em um  editText1, um outro editText2 é atualizado automaticamente, e vice versa.. é apenas um teste convertendo unidades.
Inicialmente estava tentando integrar isso com SlidingTabs, mas no meio do caminho achei esse link:

https://github.com/JulienGenoud/android-percent-support-lib-sample
Que apesar de focar no percent, ele coloca um menu slide na lateral com as activities;

Bom, separadamente os codigos funcionam perfeitamente, mas ao tentar integrar o meu codigo abaixo dentro desse app que já baixei pronto desse link, os campos não são atualizados automaticamente enquanto eu digito o valor. Para o textWatcher funcionar, tenho que fazer algo além do que tinha feito ?

**view_1.java**

```
public class view_1 extends Activity {

    double CVtokWfactor_2 = 0.7354988;
    boolean doNotEnterEd1 = false;
    boolean doNotEnterEd2 = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view1);

        final EditText ed1_2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText02_1);
        final EditText ed2_2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText02_2);


        ed1_2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (doNotEnterEd1 == true) {
                    return;
                }
                doNotEnterEd1 = true;

                try {
                    if (ed1_2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        ed2_2.setText("");
                    } else {
                        ed2_2.setText(String.format("%.3f", (Double.parseDouble(ed1_2.getText().toString()) * CVtokWfactor_2)));
                    }

                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                }
                doNotEnterEd2 = false;

            }
        });

        ed2_2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                if (doNotEnterEd2 == true) {
                    return;
                }

                doNotEnterEd1 = true;
                try {
                    if (ed2_2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        ed1_2.setText("");
                    } else {
                        ed1_2.setText(String.format("%.3f", (Double.parseDouble(ed2_2.getText().toString()) * CVtokWfactor_2)));    //Here do the conversion as you like, replace CVtokWfactor.
                    }

                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                }

                doNotEnterEd1 = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }
        });


    }


}
```

e o **view1.xml** (que apenas troquei o conteudo para meus dois campos do outro app que fiz, tirando o layout percent desse.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.juliengenoud.percentsamples.view_1">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText02_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Potência CV"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText02_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText02_1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Potência kW"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="30sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

O que acham que eu poderia fazer para isso funcionar ? Essa parte do percent para mim crei oque não é nem necessaria, se tiverem alguma outra ref para me indicar por favor.

Muito obrigado!
Barata